# How I can deepcopy cell (containing image and Colorful texts) from excel in a cell in table in word using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, python-docx

I want to copy a cell in excel , that cell containing an image and text with colors , I worked with openpxl and python docx , i tried with bellow code but it didn't well worked I can't see the image and the style of the text in Word's table cell[image]

```
import openpyxl
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=10, column=10)
from docx import Document
doc=Document('test.docx')
table=doc.tables[0]
table.cell(0,0).text=cell_obj.value
doc.save('test.docx')
```

Comment: The two libraries have different implementations of OOXML so you'll have to convert the rich text, though it shouldn't be that. The image part of the worksheet, not the cell so you'll have to work it separately as well.

Comment: It would be easier to use win32com to do this unless this is not possible. As the name suggests this would require Windows and Excel and Word installed.